# How to create custom class from variable? (not Object)

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I know I can do do the following :

```
String className = "A";
Object o= Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

But consider this case (simplification):

```
class Parent { 

   public void action() {...};
}

class A extends Parent {

 @Override
 public void action() {...};

}
class B extends Parent {

 @Override
 public void action() {...};

}
class C extends Parent {

 @Override
 public void action() {...};

}
```

Now I would like to create a class that can be either of those 3 cases. 
If I use the above code and create an Object, I wouldn't be able to call the `action` method.
I would like to be able to create an object that extends Parent from a string.

In my actuall case I have multiple different parents, and the class is extented from a class that's extended from a class and about 4 layers of inhertiance. Would regular casting work?

Comment: Is your question whether you can do `A o= (A) Class.forName(className).newInstance();`?

Comment: `Parent anyClass = (Parent) Class.forName(className).newInstance();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting would work, but is unnecessary.  [`Class#newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) returns an instance of type `T`, which is the class' generic type.  This means that because `Class.forName("A")` returns an instance of `Class<A>`, you can declare your instance as `Parent` due to `A`'s inheritance, as `newInstance()` is returning an object of type `A`.

```
Parent p = Class.forName("A").newInstance();
p.action();
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile actually, says the type found is `CAP#1`, and requires me to do casting, but casting it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since all your classes extend `Parent` you can cast result of `newInstance()` to this type and then call all methods declared in `Parent`. The "right" implementation will run.

```
Parent p = (Parent)Class.forName(className).newInstance();
p.action();
```